# Copying content from other websites and linking to the original post

Tags: seo, google-adsense, copyright

I want to create a website that will grab content from other news websites using their RSS and insert it in my database. I am only going to show the title and an excerpt with a link to the original post.

Is this a good idea? Will Google ban my website? Is it bad for SEO and is it against Google AdSense rules?

Comment: Although not a great idea, this is a good question to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create a website that will grab content from other news websites using their RSS and insert it in my database. I am only going to show the title and an excerpt with a link to the original post.
>
> Is this a good idea?

No, because you're using someone else's content

> Will Google ban my website?

If you keep it up, then Google will eventually notice, especially if the level of copying is very frequent (a.k.a. server slowdown).

> Is it bad for SEO?

bad is a light word. It's terrible because a) your content is thin, and b) your content duplicates someone else's. You should look at webmaster quality guidelines from any popular search engine such as Google.

> and is it against Google Adsense rules?

Definitely. You need original content.

Comment: This seems to be an epidemic these days. Call it the entitled generation which may not entirely be fair. I want a website that I do not have to hardly do anything with and will make me those Internet millions without doing anything at all. How do I do that? Tell me how to do it because I do not want to read and do the research. What tool do I use? Because I do not want to learn something and figure it out for myself. Tell me how to do SEO because I just do not know what buttons to push to make me millions. Lastly, Google will not index my site I put up yesterday. I cannot even wait one day.

Comment: The answer isn't entirely accurate, it may add a lot of value to the user from the perspective of search engines. Newsnow ranks very high with top key words and has been doing so for years and it's regarded as an authority site. However there are those who duplicate content the op may be of the former.